# Does the app can upload with version 3 and version code 2 for the first time?

Tags: android

I have to upload my Testing.apk to google play store with

> version code 2
>
> version name 3.1

for the first upload.
Does google allow to upload like that without start from version number ?
And after upload can I install on all the devices that already installed previous un uploaded app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can upload any apk starting with any version code, just make sure it is greater than any existing apk version code that was previously uploaded to the Google Play. If you have distributed your release apk with version 1 directly to users, yes they will be able to update their app from the play store.

Comment: if user have installed release(unpublish to google),then can install publish one from play store?

Comment: Yes, just make sure the version number is greater on the play store version and both apk are signed using same keys.